# Why is the directional derivative maximal in the direction of gradient?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

As far as I understand, if I am given a function of the form $w=f(x,y,z)$ (that represents the temperature for example) and I want to find what is the direction I should walk (if I am at $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ in order to have steepest ascend of temperature, I need to walk in the direction of $\nabla f$ .

But, assume I am on the point $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ and I can only walk on the surface $g(x,y,z)=0$. Why is the direction I should walk by is the projection of $\nabla f$ on the tangent plane to $g(x,y,z)=0$ at the point $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $P$ be the tangent plane to $g=0$. We want to maximize $\nabla f\cdot v$ subject to $v\in P$, $\|v\|=1$. Let $(v,w)$ be an orthonormal basis of $P$. A reformulation is the maximization of $x (\nabla f\cdot v)+y(\nabla f\cdot w)$ for $x^2+y^2=1$. But this is a linear function in $(x,y)$ which is, on a unit circle, maximized in a multiple of its own gradient $(\nabla f\cdot v, \nabla f\cdot w)$. So the maximal ascent in $P$ is in the direction $v (\nabla f\cdot v)+w(\nabla f\cdot w)$ which is also equal to a multiple of the projection of $\nabla f$ to $P$.

Intuitively, the steepest ascend is in the direction of $\nabla f$ and if you are not allowed to go there, then you at least want to go in the direction *as close to $\nabla f$ as possible*. But this is nothing else then the projection of $\nabla f$ to $P$.